How to detect touch based pointerenter events
I was relying on pointerType property of PointerEvent, however I'm noticing that I'm occasionally receiving this event with pointerType="mouse" on a touch device. What could be causing this? Is there a reliable way to detect the origin of the event?
I am using React if it matters, but the underlying event also has the wrong pointer type, so I'm assuming React is not an issue here.

Please paste the pointer event code you're using with a console.log for anyone to see and test. Otherwise I'd assume it's just addEventListener("pointerdown",(evt) => {   console.log(evt.pointerType, evt); }); Also, if you believe it's only related to a specific browser, OS, device - might be helpful to disclose those things as well.

I find it difficult to isolate my code, which is why it's more of a general question. Is there any situation where a browser would emit a pointer event with wrong pointer type?

Well there's nothing inherently wrong with a pointer event having type "mouse". Why do you think that's wrong? In other words, what is your testing situation, your device, etc?

For example laptops with touch screens generally also have a touchpad (essentially a mouse) or an attached USB mouse. For that matter, a tablet or a phone can have an attached Bluetooth mouse.
